# Speeding up compilation of a Node.js project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, spring-boot, npm

I have a Java Spring Boot backend and React.js frontend. I need to place compiled Node.js app into folder "static" of my Spring Boot application so it can be served as static content. This is done using the command `npm build`.

The problem with this is the compilation is quite slow and consumes several seconds before it's done. On the other hand, when I run my frontend app directly with "npm start" then projecting local code changes into my webbrowser takes only one second.

It's not acceptable for me to wait 10s or more until build into my Spring Boot is done. Is there a way to "link together" node.js project files without any optimisations, or to speed up the build?

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to a common pain point for repeatable builds, dependency installation consumes too much time. The only known workaround is to use a cache. [Here's](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-cache-install) an example. Well, some people checkin node-modules, but that's just shooting yourself in the foot.

If you're feeling adventurous, you can also consider adding [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) as proxy in your production build environment, which will help with faster docker image downloads in addition to just npm installs.

Comment: That cache solution you have mention (if I understand) seems to be only for "npm install" which is not problem for me as i'm not running this command so often.

Comment: Oh. I'd assumed that `npm build` triggered npm install, which has been an issue for me in more than a few projects. Did you get the chance to check what exactly in the build is consuming time?